# AS3 platformer generation

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I am trying to infinitely generate platforms x distance in front of the player and I pretty much have no idea where to begin. Also they cannot "stack" on top of each other. Currently, what i have is below, there are no errors, though it takes up quite a bit of memory and my game lags to the point of crashing flash cs3

```
function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void{
    //gravitate the player
    _vy += 1.5;
    //move the player
    Player.x += _vx;
    Player.y += _vy;

    //process collisions
    processCollisions();
    //Process other collisions
    processOtherCollisions();
    //scroll the stage
    scrollStage();
    //Process Key Presses
    KeyHandler();
    //Process Lives once
    LifeHandler();
    //Generate Objects
    generateObjects();
}
//Function for generating objects
var ObjectArray:Array = [];
var ChildrenColliding:Boolean = false;
function generateObjects():void{
    if(_vx > 0){
        var Square:MovieClip;
        Square = new mcSquare();
        Square.x = Math.random() * 500 + Math.abs(_boundaries.x);
        Square.y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight/2.5 + (stage.stageHeight/2.5);
        ObjectArray.push(Square);
        _boundaries.addChild(Square);
    }
    for(var i in ObjectArray){
        for(var a in ObjectArray){
            if(ObjectArray[a].hitTestObject(ObjectArray[i]) && a != i){
                ChildrenColliding = true;
            }
        }
        while(ChildrenColliding){
        ObjectArray[i].x = Math.random() * 500 + Math.abs(_boundaries.x);
        ObjectArray[i].y = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight/2.5 + (stage.stageHeight/2.5);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Ass a side note, your AS3 code is confusing from an idiomatic perspective.  Variables in AS3 tend to be camelCased (or sometimes underscore_named) where classes tend to be PascalCased.  Mixing these casings makes it difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

The code you show here is fine.  Setting `ObjectArray` as `[]` is perfectly safe and should not be null.  There must be more to the story.

Can you post the rest of your code for this class?  Do you have any other code that sets `ObjectArray`?  There must be a line of code some other place that sets `ObjectArray` which is setting it to null.

Comment: That's seriously the only place where i even touch ObjectArray or square, never is it reffered anywhere else

Comment: @Cory If it is not referenced anywhere else, what is the purpose?  Why push objects onto it?  Why is it a private member variable?  Can you show us the rest of the class?  We are missing the bigger picture and can't help you any further without seeing the rest of the code.

Comment: Well my goal is to then check the objects in the array against each other for collision in order to prevent them from stacking ontop of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just:

```
ObjectArray.push(Square);
```

Comment: that's giving me a null object reference error, when i comment out the array that error disappears

Comment: Isn't `var ObjectArray:Array = [];` defined inside some other function by chance?